# Interval notation

Tags: notation

I suspect there is a better way of expressing this:

A point $p$ that is in an interval around a point $o$, the interval extends in both directions by a constant $c$.

$o - c < p < o + c$
or
$\left|p-o\right| < c$

I think it would be far more clear to express this as "$p$ in $o \pm c$", how would I write that?

Comment: I think the two existing assertions are about the best you can do. You might prefer $p \in (o-c, o+c)$. Your suggestion is ambiguous because it's unclear whether it means the open or closed interval. PS Don't use the letter $o$ for a variable name - too much like $0$.

Comment: Ah right. That's a bit more clear. Thanks